# How can I update properties from data fetched from a database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to update the columns of the rows fetched through LINQ and the property to update is store in a string . How can I specifically update that value by checking if that property is equal to that string then change the property value and save the changes.

For example :

```
string prop_name= "Gate3";
IList<Model_name> DataList = (from q in DB.Table Select q ).toList();

if(DataList.Count <> 0)
{
    //do foreach loop and update the column name Gate3 
    // which is the property in the model .  
}
```

Comment: LINQ is used to query data, it does not manipulate the original collection. Can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: Your table should be normalized to not use columns numbered `Gate1`, `Gate2`, `Gate3`, etc. Your application should be configurable so that if it is installed at "gate #3" you can edit a setting so that the application knows which gate it's working with.

Comment: its not my application it was built way earlier when i joined the company.. Well I have to stick to this database for sometimes till i switch my job :D

Answer (score 0):

Your DB object, assuming its a DataContext object, is tracing changes in it's entities. Aftet modifing some of them, just call DB.SaveChanges() andit will commit your updates.